# Is it possible to have <sub>scripts in <option>s in html?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select, subscript

I have a drop down menu full of chemical elements. Is there any way I could format them properly? Ex: H<sub>2</sub>O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the [Unicode subscript characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts):

```
<select>
    <option>H₂O</option>
</select>
```

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/pZ3mg/

Comment: They don't seem to work in my context. They end up appearing as question marks: H?O. Good idea though!

Comment: @Shawn: Then the answer is no, because you're not allowed to have HTML tags inside of an `<option>` tag.  What is your context btw that it doesn't work in?  A certain OS environment or browser version, or custom web interface?